# Gatsby WorkerError:

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, gatsby, gatsby-image

Im new at Gatsby , when I try to start the Gatsby project `gatsby develop --port 8080`  , I'm meeting the following error:

> WorkerError: Processing C:/Users/AOmurzakov/Desktop/Job/landings/packages/project-business/.cache/gatsby-source-filesystem/6e42032743dd2dda7e331865dd496bd9.png failed
>     Original error:
>
> - jobs-manager.js:314 exports.enqueueJob
>     [landings]/[gatsby]/dist/utils/jobs-manager.js:314:23
>
>   - runMicrotasks
>   - task_queues.js:93 processTicksAndRejections
>       internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5
>
> not finished run queries - 2.879s not finished Generating image
>   thumbnails - 2.859s
>
> pages
>   In Progress
>   @project/businessnpm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR!
>   lerna@ project-business: `cd packages/project-business && gatsby
>   develop --port 8080` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed
>   at the lerna@ start:project-business script. npm ERR! This is probably
>   not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output
>   above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\AOmurzakov\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-02-12T05_22_16_490Z-debug.log
>   PS C:\Users\AOmurzakov\Desktop\Job\landings>

I was trying to delete .cach by `gatsby clean` . It didnt work
Also I was trying to start the project with

> 12 and 10 version of Node

But it had no effect , same error. Can someone advise ?

Answer (score 4):

Following [this](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/13442#issuecomment-507532667) GitHub comment and the one above it.

I ran the following commands and it solved the problem in my case.

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json
npm cache clear --force
npm install
npm run dev
```